# chown command does not work to give permissons for sqlite database

Tags: python, django, sqlite, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a django app deployed on digital ocean.

When I try to use functions of it that write in the database I get a permission error.

On the digitalocean website I found the following solution;`chown django:django db.sqlite3`
My username on my server isn't django, so i ran the command with my username.

Nothing changed. **What can I do?**

Edit:

ran `chown www-data:www-data db.sqlite3` because I think www-data is the user who runs the server, but still nothing changed.

Comment: What is the *user* under which the server runs. Often that is *not* the username. As a security measure, it uses a separate user that has specific rights, that should be the owner of the file.

Comment: The user that I started the server with was the root user, but I thought he had the permissions anyway

Comment: yes, but normally the root user will *never* be the user that runs the Django server (the root user normally will capture the port, and run the Django server under a much more limited user). If it would be the root user, then a small security vulnerability could mean someone can take over the server entirely.

Comment: nginx: worker process is run by www-data but give this user the permissions does not help

Comment: Do I have to restart anything? tried restarting gunicorn and nginx but nothing changed

Comment: what does ls -l return for that file

Comment: www-data has all permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out.

 It wasn't enough to give permissions to the database, but I also had to give permissions to the folder the database was in.

So the solution:

```
chown user:user djangodir
chown user:user djangodir/db.sqlite3
```